# exchange bits of an integer number in fortran

Tags: binary, fortran

suppose you have the number 2 whose binary representation is 0010
How can you exchange bits located at positions 0 and 2, and bit at 1 and 3?
so that the outcome is 1000 which is the number 8?

If I try using `mvbits` to exchange bits 0 and 2:

```
integer :: s1
s1= 2
call mvbits(s1,1,1,s1,3)
```

the result is the number `10`

Is there an intrinsic function for such an operation?

Comment: Can you explain why you think that use of `mvbits` may be suitable for that exchange?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mvbit` copies the bits.  It does not move the bits, where it seems you want to have the moved bits reset to zero.  What you have discovered is essentially an allowed aliasing issue.  You are copy 1 from 0010 to third position to get 1010.  Consider the following:

```
program foo
   implicit none
   integer(1) i, j
   j = 0
   i = 2
   call mvbits(i, 1, 1, j, 3) 
   write(*,'(B8.8,1X,B8.8,1X,2I3)') i, j, i, j
   call mvbits(i, 1, 1, j, 3) 
   write(*,'(B8.8,1X,B8.8,1X,2I3)') i, j, i, j
end program foo
```

Edit: Forgot to mention that `integer(1)` is not portable.  It is an 8-bit integer with gfortran.